# jQuery chosen-select prevent hiding of select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I want to hide a select with the chosen-select class applied if it has no elements except it doesn't work.

Ive tried

```
   $("#Category2").hide();
```

and then removing the chosen-select class prior to hide attempt:

```
 $("#Category2").remove("chosen-select");
$("#Category2").hide();
```

but neither approach works. If I don't do:

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen();
```

then the select will hide. Also no errors in Chrome Developer tools console.

Is this a known issue? Is there a "trick" to doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chosen creates additional elements - try `$("#Category2_chosen").hide();`.
See it work: http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/9UB23/

Edit for further explanation:

Try using your browser's development tools to inspect the DOM elements (usually right-click on the element, then "Inspect element" or similar).

You'll see that once you call `$(element).chosen()` on a DOM element, the following things happen:

1. the original element is hidden (it will still be in the DOM but have `style="display: none;"`)
2. the chosen drop-down widget is created using a number of other DOM elements, which are all grouped into a div of class `chosen-container` and an id which is derived from the element's id (in this case by appending "_chosen" to it)

The underscore doesn't have any special meaning, it's simply chosen's way of creating another unique id. It could just as append "-chosen" or "_mycustomsuffix".

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Can you give me a little more info? I dont get how it changed the name? When i did alert($("#Category2")) i got an object reference so something was there under just that name? Is underscore "special"?

Comment: @rism I updated the post with further explanations - your element doesn't change its id, it is merely hidden and "replaced" (visually) by other DOM elements which have other ids

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select#chosen-select").hide()
```

should do the trick.